# Display links from message as a link

Tags: reactjs, jsx, render

I'm trying to replay any occurrence of a link in a text as a link, but I only get it to show the `<a href="example.com">example.com</a>` as text in the message. (Just to be clear, it shows other message content if there is other content in the message than the link, but the link gets "linkified(as seen below)")

Here is the message component.

```
import React from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import { Comment, Image } from "semantic-ui-react";

const isOwnMessage = (message, user) => {
  return message.user.id === user.uid ? "message__self" : "";
};

const isImage = message => {
  return message.hasOwnProperty("image");
};

const timeFromNow = timestamp => moment(timestamp).fromNow();

function linkify(text) {
  var urlRegex =/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
  return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
      return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
  });
}

const Message = ({ message, user }) => (
  <Comment>
    <Comment.Avatar src={message.user.avatar} />
    <Comment.Content className={isOwnMessage(message, user)}>
      <Comment.Author as="a">{message.user.name}</Comment.Author>
      <Comment.Metadata>{timeFromNow(message.timestamp)}</Comment.Metadata>
      {isImage(message) ? (
        <Image src={message.image} className="message__image" />
      ) : (
        <div>
<Comment.Text>{linkify(message.content)}</Comment.Text>
        <React.Fragment dangerouslySetInnerHTML={linkify(message.content)}>
        </React.Fragment>
        </div>
      )}
    </Comment.Content>
  </Comment>
);

export default Message;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. dangerouslySetInnerHTML prop needs an object with `__html` property
2. [don't use React.Fragment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12014) when using dangerouslySetInnerHTML. Just use a div

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dangerouslysetinnerhtml-issue-fix-x3geg?file=/src/App.js:51-808)

**Code Snippet**

```js
function linkify(text) {
  var urlRegex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gi;
  return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
    return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + "</a>";
  });
}
const text = `I'm trying to replay any occurrence of a link in a text as a link, but I only get it to show the <a href="example.com">example.com</a> as text in the message. (Just to be clear, it shows other message content if there is other content in the message than the link, but the link gets "linkified(as seen below)")`;
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <br />
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: linkify(text) }} />; }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you better treat your `url` variable first by your regex then return like a valid react element:

```
function linkify(text) {
  const urlRegex =/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
  // extract your url by urlRegex something like
  const url = text.match(urlRegex)[0]
  return <a href={url} >{url}</a>
}
```